# Remove Previous Mark on New Mark

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a map/location sharing website for my universities Library. I use an HTML5 canvas element to display the map and allow for a mark to be placed where you click.

Currently if you miss click you have to click the clear button which clears local storage and reloads the page to remove the mark in order to be able to place a new one. I'd prefer to have a way to clear the previous mark when you click somewhere else but I can't seem to think of how to do it. In addition if there's a way to clear the marks without reloading the page that would be awesome.

Thanks for any suggestions you have.

You can see the website **[here](http://whereareutes.com/Level1.html)**

**Here is the relevant HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Main -->
<section id="main">
    <h1>Level 5</h1>
    <p>Simply tap your location and then hit share</p>
    <div class="mobileShow">
        On mobile: just drag with one finger around the box below and then tap your location.
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <canvas id="mapCan" width="868px" height="828px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="mapButtons" style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">

        <input id="Clr1" type="button" onclick="clearMark()" value="Clear">
        <input id="Shr1" type="button" onclick="saveImg() " value="Share">
        <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="form1">
            <input name="hidden_data" id='hidden_data' type="hidden"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <h1><a href="index.html">Back To Main Page</a></h1>
```

**Here is the Relevant JS**

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    var mapCan = document.getElementById('mapCan');
    var share = document.getElementById('Shr1');
    var clear = document.getElementById('Clr1');

    var img = new Image(),
            count = 0;
    img.src = '../images/Maps/L5.png';


    img.onload = function draw() {
        renderMarks();

        mapCan.onclick = function (e) {

            var rect = mapCan.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    x = e.clientX - rect.left,
                    y = e.clientY - rect.top;
            if (count == 0) {
                addMark(x, y);
                renderMarks();
            } else {
                renderMarks();
            }
        }
    }
    function renderMarks() {
        var ctx = mapCan.getContext('2d'),
                w = mapCan.width,
                h = mapCan.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
        var marks = localStorage.getItem('marks'),
                i = 0;
        console.log(marks);
        if (marks !== null) {

            marks = JSON.parse(marks);

            ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;

            for (; i < marks.length; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(marks[i][0], marks[i][1], 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }

    function addMark(x, y) {

        var marks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('marks') || '[]');
        marks.push([x, y]);
        localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(marks));
        count++;
    }

    clear.onclick = function clearMark() {
        window.localStorage.clear();
        location.reload(true);
    }
```

Comment: save all the params for everything you draw on the canvas in an array/object. write a function that will loop through and clear and redraw all the stuff you need on the canvas. when you need to clear an item, instead of making the user start over, just remove an element from the array and call the redraw function again. this is how i do it. btw you can clear the canvas by assigning it's width to it;s width, ie, `myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width;`

Comment: Hi Hayden, you just need to, onClick, pull the mark from the marks array 'marks.pull()' and call the function renderMarks() again

Comment: yeah, what that guy said, sorry didn't read your code..

Comment: Thanks for the ideas you got me on the right track and I got it working. I add a subtraction to the count in the clear mark function and changed the onclick function to ' 

if (count == 0) {
                    addMark(x, y);
                    renderMarks();
                } else {
                 clearMark();
                 addMark(x, y);
                    renderMarks();
                }'